# Why does f'(0) not exist for this piecewise defined function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Q: Does $f'(0)$ exist?

$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
      0 & x= 0 \\
      x\sin(\frac{9}{x}) & x\ne 0
\end{cases}
$

Why or why not?

How about if the $x$ in front of sine changes to $x^3$ or $x^2$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! What've you tried ? Did you try to compute $f'(0)$ by definition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tangent of $x\sin(1/x)$ at $x = 0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514809/is-there-a-tangent-of-x-sin1-x-at-x-0)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f(x)=x^a\sin\frac{9}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$, then
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=x^{a-1}\sin\frac{9}{x},$$
from which you can deduce that the limit as $x\longrightarrow 0$ exists if and only if $a>1$.

Answer (score -1):

You can compute the derivative of each possibility in the piecewise function and check for consistency at $x=0$

$$
f'=\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x=0 \\
            \sin\left(\frac{9}{x}\right)-\frac{9}{x}\cos\left(\frac{9}{x}\right) & \quad x \neq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
If both approach the same value as $x \to 0$ then the derivative exists.

For different $x^a$ you have:

$$
f'=\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x=0 \\
            ax^{a-1}\sin\left(\frac{9}{x}\right)-9x^{a-2}\cos\left(\frac{9}{x}\right) & \quad x \neq 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Again, check if the limits are equal.

Comment: This is actually not true.

Comment: @Mathgemini Why not? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Firstly, you cannot first compute the derivative (which presupposes that it exists) and then check if it exists. And even if $f'(0)$ exists, we do not necessarily have that $\lim\limits_{0\neq x\longrightarrow 0}f'(x)=f'(0)$, because that's the statement that $f'$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: @Mathgemini The converse is true though, which is what my answer says. If $f'$ is continuous at zero then $f'(0)$ exists

Comment: You cannot go about showing that $f'$ is continuous at $0$ without already knowing that $f'(0)$ exists.