# Find the condition for which the following function is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Let us consider the function
  $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^p\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^q}\right), & \text{ if } x\neq 0\\
0, & \text{ if  } x=0
\end{cases}$$
Where $p,q\in\mathbf{R}$.
For which values of $p,q$ the above function is continuous and differentiable.

I have tried in this way:

To show continuity,
$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^p\sin(\frac{1}{x^q})=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^{p-q}x^q \sin(\frac{1}{x^q})$

For differentiability,
 $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^{p-1}\sin(\frac{1}{x^q})$

What can I say after this?

Comment: Since you have not begun anywhere, here is a starter: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514809/is-there-a-tangent-of-x-sin1-x-at-x-0

Comment: @imranfat, sorry, I can't understand the problem what is saying the above link

Comment: @user356595 It is your situation for the case p=q=1

Comment: @imranfat, $p=q=1$ is a particular case, in my problem, $p,q$ are any real numbers

Comment: True, but when you first study particular cases, you get a better grip on the problem. Then you can move towards a general case.